# Convert two dimentional array into the json object in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, object, multidimensional-array

I am converting a two-dimensional array into a JSON object.

Now my controller returning this output:

```js
[
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "V1",
            "project_id": 1
        }
    ],
    []
]
```

Want to convert it like:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Laravel"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Wordpress"
  }
]
```

My controller code:

```php
$user = auth()->user();
$projectVersions = array();

foreach($user->projects as $project)
{
    $projectId = $project->pivot->project_id;
    $projectVersions[] = Version::where('project_id', $projectId)
        ->where('created_by', $user->id)
        ->get();
}

return $projectVersions;
```

When I am using below code which is suggested by @John Lobo, it is returning below output:

```js
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Hadayat Niazi",
  "email": "niazicr801@gmail.com",
  "is_admin": 0,
  "email_verified_at": null,
  "created_at": "2021-06-11T15:13:00.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-06-11T15:13:00.000000Z",
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Laravel",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 2,
        "project_id": 1
      },
      "versions": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "V1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Displaying the user projects and versions:

Again I am updating the code for @John Lobo, he want to look the output

```php
$user = User::with(['projects', 'projects.versions'])
    ->find(auth()->user()->id);

$result = $user->projects->map(function ($project) {
    return [
        $project->versions,
    ];
});

return $result;
```

Output the code

```js
[
    [
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "V1",
                "project_id": 1,
                "version": "1.22",
                "created_by": 2,
                "is_publish": 0,
                "feature": "<b>In this ipdate asdsdasd</b>",
                "bug_fix": "<p><b>sdfdffffffffff</b></p>",
                "created_at": "2021-06-12T08:08:21.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-06-12T08:08:21.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "v2",
                "project_id": 1,
                "version": "2.12",
                "created_by": 2,
                "is_publish": 0,
                "feature": "adsdasdsadas",
                "bug_fix": "sddasdas",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        []
    ]
]
```

Comment: show controller code

Comment: Have you used `json_encode()` with your response

Comment: can you post project model

Comment: Is this line getting multiple data `$projectVersions[] = Version::where('id', $projectId)->get() ;` or you want single row?

Comment: Do you want the projects with their versions or just the versions? Your models will also be helpful

Answer (score 1):

In controller you can do the following.if you have relation in project model called version

```
  $projectVersions=User::with(['projects','projects.version'])->find(auth()->user()->id);
    
  return $projectVersions->projects;
```

I believe Project model has below relationship

```
public function version(){

return $this->hasMany(Version::class);
}
```

**Updated**

```
$user=User::with(['projects','projects.versions'])->find(auth()->user()->id);

    $result = $user->projects->map(function ($project) {

        return $project->versions;
    });

 dd($result);
```

Comment: it's working but it is returning all the users and their project and their versions, I don't want these all. I want to display only logged user projects and their versions.

Comment: its not get it should be first().its my mistake

Comment: you can do like this also $projectVersions=User::with(['projects','projects.version'])->find(auth()->user()->id);

Comment: it's working but I want to return only the versions becuase I need to pass it to the laravel yajra datatable.

Comment: can you show what this query returns and what your expecting result

Comment: Now it's returning the user project and their version. please tell me how can I display only versions not any other things like their projects etc.

Comment: still it's retuning their projects, I don't want to display projects bro, i need to pass them into the datatable plugin it will throw error, i need only versions, like Version::where()->where()->get();

Comment: instead of this return [
            'name'=>$project->name,
            'title'=>$project->versions->title,
        ];  you can return $project->versions

Comment: yes it retuning the projects but it wrapped output json into three array

Comment: can you show your final code in controlelr

Comment: I updated the code and output, please have a look at it.

Comment: @HadiNiazi you did not write the same code as @JohnLobo, see what you are returning in the `map` and what is Lobo returning in his `map`... he fixed it, copy paste as him and it will work

Comment: @HadiNiazi.r return [
        $project->versions,
    ];  to return $project->versions;

Comment: @matiaslauriti I know this code is working but it still wrapping the data into two dimentional array, I want to wrap data in a single array with JSON objects. I'll pass this data to laravel yajra datatable. yajra did not accept two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Use like below

```
$json = json_encode($responseOfController);
echo "<pre>";print_r($json);die;
```

Comment: Can you please share your response that you're getting?